# How to update docker-compose on Docker for Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I've installed Docker for Windows on my machine (Windows 10, Hyper-V). Version is 18.03.0-ce. But the version of docker-compose is 1.20.1. I want to run docker-compose with a docker-compose.yml file containing the property version : '2'. I get the error:

*client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version*

How can i upgrade to a newer version of docker-compose?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#upgrading follow this link.

Comment: did you find answer? I have same troubles, and can't upgrade docker-compose in toolbox-package. Upper documentation link did not give receipt

Answer (score 21):

I do not know you have still the same issue or not. Please check "version" value in the docker-compose.yml file should be more than "2". For me I changed it to "2.1" and it worked.
version: '2.1' in the compose file is the minimum supported version for Windows containers. I found it from here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/268

Comment: For the record I have just had this issue on Ubuntu and this fix still works.

Comment: Today on Ubuntu Focal 20.04.6 LTS the exact same issue. The version update to '2.1' did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

ERROR : client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version

The above error will be resolve by simply changing the version as from 2.0 to 2.1 in your docker-compose.yml file

I have searched so many sites but even I could not find the root-cause, exact reason and how it is resolving by changing the version number in our compose file.

It will be helpful to all of us if anyone post the root cause and solution

Comment: This worked for me but I couldn't find out why. It's not mentioned in the documentation either.

Answer (score 3):

Please Update version `"2.0" to "2.1"`

### docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '2.1'services:
  web:
    build: flask/.
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  mysql:
    build: db/.
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: vs_engine
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Changing the compose file API version will have no effect on the installed docker compose version.

Comment: will you please upgrade your docker container. old version of docker containers could also rise the this type of problem.